# Are jQuery tabs overkill in this case?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, tabs

I'd like to create a content box with two tabs.  Each tab is associated with a table which contain server-side data.  My thought right now is just to load the page with 10 rows worth of data for each table and hide/display each table respectively to begin.

I was then going to toggle display of the tabbed content based on either click events on the tabs OR GET parameters relating to which tabbed content is being acted on (through pagination, for example).

Should I just handle this with UI tabs or is toggling display reasonable in this case? Since the user can update their data, I assume that caching via the tab UI isn't helpful in this case.

Thanks, 
Brendan

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, I don't think its going to be overkill. If you are worried about performance, ten rows for 2 tables is just 20, which is not much. Paginating will also get 10 more rows for each 'click' so it's still good there.

Do use tab activation through click events, but *also* use GET parameters to know in which page the user currently is, from which tab.

Regarding caching data that you know will change, it might be unnecessary (see my 1st paragraph). Caching can sometimes become unwieldy, so don't add an uneccesary layer of complexity.

As someone who suggests simplicity above all else, I'd discard the whole 'tab loading' thing but leaving the tabs per se (i.e. the interface elements that will be clicked) and when the user clicks each tab, it takes to another page with the tabs too, old-fashioned style.

Comment: thank YO. I guess this was an open-ended question so I appreciate the insightful response